# ran lower to the ground vs ran low to the ground

Tags: grammaticality

Can you explain to me why author have used word "lower" instead of "low". The text is:

> I was too far away to see anyone, so I parked behind a big rock at the base of the mountain, left my helmet there, and hurried into the tall grass. The trees were about 200 yards away when I ducked and ran **lower** to the ground.

Is that correct to tell "ran lower to the ground"?.

Comment: If you *ran **lower** to the ground*, the implication is that someone else (or perhaps *you*, previously) ran "higher". If you ran ***low***, that implication is weaker or non-existent (you just that way at that time, with no element of "comparison" to anything else).

Answer (score 1):

By ducking (meaning to crouch down), they are running lower than they would be when running in a normal position.  "Lower" is used to compare the ducking run to a normal run.  Either could work and I would say they could be interchangeable in this instance.

Comment: Exactly. Whatever height they were running at in relation to the ground *before*, they started to run *lower* than that.